# Adding progress bar (UIProgressView) for text or email for iPhone

Tags: iphone

Does anyone have tutorials or code snippets to add a Progress Bar for the MFMessageComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController?  I'm assuming you could add a progress bar as a subview, but not really sure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be hesitant about trying to modify those view controllers. The documentation specifically says that you shouldn't try to mess with them in that way, as they are meant to be displayed "as is". In any case, why don't you try adding a `UIProgressView` to the view controller's view? If not, you could add it directly to the window—generally ill-advised—at the appropriate time and remove it when you're done.

By the way, why are you trying to add a progress view to those view controllers? Those controllers don't provide any sort of state about whether a message was sent successfully or not, only whether or not the user canceled the operation.

Comment: Tizma Yeah they don't provide any information to the user I guess is my concern.  There is only sound.  I mean I could pop up an alert view saying the message was sent, but I feel like something should be given to the user.

Comment: You mean for SMS? For e-mail, it's possible that the connection can't be made and so the e-mail will be sent to the Outbox or Drafts or something. So you have no idea whether or not the message actually sent. Same with SMS. :-\